# Resize and relocate Alaska and Hawaii on US county map with R

Tags: r, united-states

How can I resize, relocate and frame Alaska and Hawaii on a US county map, to look more like a traditional map of the fifty states (and DC)?

I've loaded Esri's US county shapefile into R:

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
# Download from www.baruch.cuny.edu/confluence/display/geoportal/ESRI+USA+Data and unzip
counties.shp <- readShapeSpatial("counties.shp")
```

I've processed and merged the shapes and data:

```
library(ggplot2)
counties.shp.f <- fortify(counties.shp, region = "FIPS")
cty_map <- merge(counties.shp.f, cty_pop_msa[,c(2:3,5:6)], by.x="id", by.y="cty_geoid", all.x=TRUE)
cty_map <- cty_map[order(cty_map$order),]
```

I've plotted a choropleth map of MSA counties:

```
library(ggmap)
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = cty_map, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = metro), 
               color = "black", size = 0.25) + 
  coord_map(xlim=c(-200,-50), ylim=c(25,70)) + theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```

However, Alaska and Hawaii are represented to scale and in their proper locations (I guess), which makes the contiguous US barely legible in A4 format, Hawai invisible, and Alaska too emphasized :

[image]

What I need is something more like this, in terms of Alaska's and Hawaii's relative sizes and positions, e.g. sized to fit south-west of Texas and framed:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767984/7114709) but am hard put to transpose it to my own data.

Comment: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/albersusa … https://rud.is/b/2014/11/16/moving-the-earth-well-alaska-hawaii-with-r/ … https://github.com/pdil/usmap #googleisyourfriend

Comment: @hrbrmstr Fantastic. Are there easy ways to frame Alaska and Hawaii and/or display an indication of scale for each of the three blocks?

Comment: Now, *that* is a gd question. There's another approach: http://r-nold.blogspot.com/2014/06/creating-inset-map-with-ggplot2.html (it might need tweaking with newer ggplot2 changes) would be an easier way to go IMO.